# Error in foo[i, ] number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run the following code:

```
# ncand = 91

foo <- matrix(nrow=(ncand), ncol=8)
colnames(foo) <- c("Current.avg", "Atten.avg", "Oxygen.avg", "IceCov.avg", "Thick.avg", "Prim.avg", "Salinity.avg", "Temp.avg")

for (i in 1:length(cand$snp)) {
  nam <- cand[i,2]
  snp.gen <- gen[,nam]
  foo[i,] <- apply(pred,2,function(x) cor(x,snp.gen))
}
```

But I am getting the error,

```
Error in foo[i, ] <- apply(pred, 2, function(x) cor(x, snp.gen)) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I have tried using and ifelse statement to see if that would remedy the problem:

```
foo[i,] <- apply(pred,2,ifelse(function(x) cor(x,snp.gen)))
```

But I get another error code:

```
Error in as.logical(test) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'logical'
```

And that is where I'm stuck. I feel I went down the wrong path by using ifelse, I'm not entirely sure.

Here is what pred looks like:

```
# A tibble: 112 x 7
   Current.avg Atten.avg Oxygen.avg Thick.avg Prim.avg Salinity.avg Temp.avg
         <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 2      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 3      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 4      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 5      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 6      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 7      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 8      0.0659     3.01        363.     1.75  0.00683          31.2   -0.339
 9      0.0194     0.564       365.     0.568 0.000994         31.0   -0.853
10      0.0194     0.564       365.     0.568 0.000994         31.0   -0.853
# ... with 102 more rows

#And here's what cand$snp looks like
cand$snp
 [1] "L0080" "L0176" "L0198" "L0223" "L0354" "L0382" "L0456" "L0490" "L0502" "L0533" "L0566" "L0612" "L0713" "L0766"
[15] "L0881" "L0886" "L0919" "L0977" "L1048" "L1100" "L1116" "L1277" "L1291" "L1435" "L1439" "L1466" "L1491" "L1535"
[29] "L1732" "L1775" "L1781" "L1782" "L1807" "L1815" "L1989" "L2069" "L2070" "L2101" "L2109" "L2111" "L2203" "L2209"
[43] "L2250" "L2349" "L2407" "L2473" "L2540" "L2546" "L2559" "L2587" "L2603" "L2626" "L2648" "L2657" "L2687" "L2785"
[57] "L2824" "L2831" "L2866" "L2906" "L2949" "L2952" "L2957" "L3062" "L3067" "L0139" "L0175" "L0176" "L0190" "L0469"
[71] "L0522" "L0552" "L0553" "L0890" "L0984" "L1100" "L1746" "L1760" "L2897" "L2968" "L3007" "L0461" "L0701" "L1100"
[85] "L1134" "L1724" "L1731" "L1958" "L2062" "L2148" "L2299"
```

For more context on what I am trying to run, the entire code is here in the "Let’s add in the correlations of each candidate SNP with the eight environmental predictors" section:

https://popgen.nescent.org/2018-03-27_RDA_GEA.html

Comment: The second error seems fairly clear: `function(x) cor(x,snp.gen)` is not a logical vector. It's an R expression that evaluates to a function call. We cannot really help with the first error when we have not information about what `pred` might be.

Comment: I just updated the original question to give you an indicated of what the pred dataset is all about.

Comment: What is `foo` here? Has it been declared before that for loop? It looks like you're trying to squeeze in a vector into a single element with `foo[i,] <- apply(pred, 2, function(x) cor(x, snp.gen))`? Some additional context might be helpful.

Comment: I just updated the question to have what foo is, and what the "ncand" is that's associated with it! Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to help.

Comment: Could you please indicate what `cand` looks like? And the link you posted does have the code, but no easy way to get the data. And it looks like you've either modified the code or are using different data.